# Detect change in two values

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I currently use a prometheus alertmanager alert to determine the number of boxes that are running at a given time.

I would like to create an alert that will alarm if the number of online boxes changes.  I use something like this:

```
sum(up{app="mybox"}) != sum(up{app="mybox"} offset 5m)
```

This will detect a state change, but it does not report the current / previous value.  All $labels.value will return is a true/false.  Is there a way to write this query so that A) it both alarms on change, and B) reports the different values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen in [alert templating](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/#templating), there is only one `$value` available which is the expression of the rule.

In you case, it will be the new value of `sum(up{app="mybox"})`. Depending on your use case, you could express it as

- an increase: `sum(up{app="mybox"}) - sum(up{app="mybox"} offset 5m) != 0`
- a change ratio: `1 - clamp_max(sum(up) / sum(up{app="mybox"} offset 5m), 0) != 0`

If you really need the other (previous) value, you can use [a query template](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/template_reference/#queries) but don't put it in a label. Otherwise, a different alert will be generated for each previous value.

```
expr: sum(up{app="mybox"}) != sum(up{app="mybox"} offset 5m)
annotations:
   description: The new value {{ $value }} is different from the previous: {{with query "sum(up{app='mybox'} offset 5m)"}}{{ . | first | value}}{{end}}.
```

Note: the query may be simplified in your case but I wrote the general case.